# Expression evaluation in java from String

Tags: java, expression

I want to create a method where the input is a String which is an equation and which returns the result of the equation.

Something like this

```
String s;
s = "23*14*(15-4)";
System.out.println(ecuation(s));
```

I found a java program, that evaluates an equation, but I have no idea how to adapt it to my needs. Anyone can help?

```
public class Evaluate {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Stack<String> ops  = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<Double>();

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String s = StdIn.readString();
            if      (s.equals("("))               ;
            else if (s.equals("+"))    ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals("-"))    ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals("*"))    ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals("/"))    ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals("sqrt")) ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals(")")) {
                String op = ops.pop();
                double v = vals.pop();
                if      (op.equals("+"))    v = vals.pop() + v;
                else if (op.equals("-"))    v = vals.pop() - v;
                else if (op.equals("*"))    v = vals.pop() * v;
                else if (op.equals("/"))    v = vals.pop() / v;
                else if (op.equals("sqrt")) v = Math.sqrt(v);
                vals.push(v);
            }
            else vals.push(Double.parseDouble(s));
        }
        StdOut.println(vals.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: To contribute to this process it would be helpful to let us know if you tried anything besides looking at the program.  Did you run it?  What input did you use?  What was the result?

Comment: What I posted here is a code of a class Evaluate, what I want is a method that gets a String as input and returs a result under a Double value.

Comment: @user1445967 I have no idea where to get StdIn and StdOut. I tried to run it... I search on google for StdIn and StdOut, built the classes for them, but when I run the program nothing happens. E: I managed to make it work but still no result being displayed.

Comment: `StdIn` and `StdOut` are just `System.in` and `System.out`

Comment: `StdIn` and `StdOut` *are not* `System.in` or `System.out`.  First, where do they declared as such?  Secondly, `InputStream` *does not* have a method `readString()`.  They are calling static methods of classes provided in different files.  Searching Google for them _will not work_, you need the _exact files_ that go with this `Evaluate` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Evaluate` program you found is reading each token in the expression (supposedly from STDIN) and working on it. If you were to reuse this program you need to

1. write a tokenator that would generate tokens out of the string expression

   - i.e. returns "23*14*(15-4)" as a list of `[ 23, *, 13, *, (, 15, -, 4, ) ]`
2. refactor the main method to take an `Iterator<String>` and iterator through it where the `next()` method returns the next token in the list.
3. pass the list.iterator() from the list generated in #1 above to the refactored method in #2.

HTH.